# Div tag vertical scroll not working with relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

Please check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Utwb/2/) . I am desiging a page with 2 section with indepedent scroll bar for each section. I set the style for body as

```
height:100%
overflow:hidden;
```

and set

```
height:100%;
overflow:scroll
```

for both of the div. but the scroll bar doesn't work. I could not set the position as absolute or fixed , since I'm using a responsive UI . If I use absolute/fixed its making some problems when I resize the window to some smaller resolution. How to solve this without changing the position property of these elements?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're giving the DIVS that you want to scroll 100% height so they don;t have to scroll as they are tall enough to show all their content. Set them to a smaller height.

Comment: If everything is set to `height: 100%` and it all fits inside the window height... there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: I want to limit the window size as the height of the screen/display area. Thats why I set height as 100%. If this is not the correct way how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `body` and `html` at `height:100%`. See a simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bYXRT/

Comment: its working in jsfiddle but when I make these modifications in my files the scroll is not working and the overflow is not displaying

Comment: Check your HTML structure and avoid using containers that you don't really need.

Answer (score -1):

Give your div width is fix in px

```
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: How to set the height as height of the window?